# _Some_ widgets not displaying

Tags: magento-enterprise, cms, widgets

Trying to display some featured products on the homepage using widgets. The first product will show up, the other will not. I cannot find anything in the Apache error log, Magento's system.log, nor exception.log. Can anybody help me debug this?

**CMS Code**

```
{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_link"
         anchor_text="Product A" 
         template="catalog/product/widget/link/link_block.phtml" 
         id_path="product/223552"}}
{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_link"
         anchor_text="Product B" 
         template="catalog/product/widget/link/link_block.phtml" 
         id_path="product/261339"}}
```

Some things to note:

- The order of the widgets does not matter, 223552 always shows up while 261339 does not
- Flat product table is enabled

  - Both 223552 and 261339 exist in the flat product table
  - I did not notice any missing attributes in 261339 that may be required
- Both products are enabled and are visible
- Have cleared cache and full page cache, no effect
- Have reindexed everything, no effect

Answer (score 2):

If we look at `Mage_Catalog_Block_Widget_Link::_toHtml` (which is the class that block extends) we can see that nothing will be output if there is no href. Investigation of `getHref` in the same class will show that the only way this can return false is:

```
$urlRewriteResource = Mage::getResourceSingleton('core/url_rewrite');
$href = $urlRewriteResource->getRequestPathByIdPath($this->getData('id_path'), $store);
if (!$href) {
    return false;
}
```

So best guest would be that if you have a multistore setup, the product isn't associated with the store. Otherwise the value is assumably just not in the table, check your core_rewrite_table for the value `product/261339` in the id_path. If it's not there the your url reindex either needs running or is not completing correctly.

Comment: Very helpful. I assumed (incorrectly) that the `'core/url_rewrite'` model would be searching the new `enterprise_url_rewrite` table as well. It is not.